# Java : how to terminate condition check inside for loop

Tags: java

I have a Array List as shown .

My requirement is that , if the List consists of the value **"M"** in it , i want to terminate the Condition check (equals check as shown ) in the for loop , but want to continue   further operations  in that for loop

This is my program

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Jai {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String flag = null;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("M");
        list.add("M");
        list.add("M");
        list.add("F");
        list.add("M");
        list.add("M");
        list.add("M");
        list.add("F");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals("M")) {
                flag = "M";
            } else {
                flag = "F";
            }
            // this is to indicate that i need to continue further operations
            // inside for loop
            System.out.println("Hi");

        }

        if (flag.equals("M"))
            System.out.println("This is M List");
        else
            System.out.println("This is F List");

    }
}
```

The List is consisting of Value M in it , so i want to treat it as M List .

The above program is for Simplicity , actually the List will contain Employee Objects in it .

Comment: continue is the keyword you are looking for..

Comment: Change `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {` to `for (int i = 0; i < list.size() && !flag.equals("M"); i++) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is what you are looking for

```
    boolean hasSeenM = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if ( !hasSeenM && list.get(i).equals("M")) {
            hasSeenM = true;
        }
        // this is to indicate that i need to continue further operations
        // inside for loop
        System.out.println("Hi");

    }

    if (hasSeenM)
        System.out.println("This is M List");
    else
        System.out.println("This is F List");
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to test if the list contains "M". The clean way to do that is not to use a for loop, but simply to call

```
if (list.contains("M"))
```

To answer your question, though, you can break out of the loop using

```
if (list.get(i).equals("M")) {
    flag = "M";
    break;
}
```

If you actually want to do something in the loop only if the element is not M, then do

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).equals("M")) {
        flag = "M";
    } 
    else {
        flag = "F";
        doSomethingOnlyForNonMElements();
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to continue with the rest of the loop's iterations though, he'll be wanting a `continue`, not a `break`.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl, the loop will continue as usual, what the op needs is to break if it gets `M`

Comment: Then he doesn't need anything. The code in the question will continue iterating. @user974802: your question is not clear. PLease provide example input and output.

Comment: @JB Nizet , the list will consists of EMployee Objects , not Strings , for simplicity i provided sample example .

Comment: break will terminate me from the entire for loop .

Comment: As I said, your question is not clear. What do you want to do exactly? If you want to do something in the loop only when the current element is not M, then do it in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it the following way

```
// Indicates whether the list has M or not
boolean hasM = false;

// Go over the entire list
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // Check if we found M within the list, if not, proceed
    // to checking if the current item has M in it.
    if (!hasM && list.get(i).equals("M")) {
        // The current item is M, set hasM to true
        hasM = true;
    }

    // this is to indicate that i need to continue further operations
    // inside for loop
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

Checking a boolean value is a cheaper operation than comparing a String. An `if` must be part of that loop unless you are willing to break it and continue another loop that discludes that check like the following

```
// Indicates whether the list has M or not
boolean hasM = false;

// Remember the position of iteration
int i;

// Go over the list, until we find M
for (i = 0; i < list.size() && !hasM; i++) {
    // Since this loop will only iterate until M is found,
    // we can remove the check for whether M was found or not
    if (list.get(i).equals("M")) {
        // The current item is M, set hasM to true
        hasM = true;
    }

    // this is to indicate that i need to continue further operations
    // inside for loop
    System.out.println("Hi");
}

// Continue in a different loop. If this loop iterates, it
// will be after M was found.
for (; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // Do stuff after M was found
}
```

As stated in JB Nizet answer, you can use `list.contains("M")` to test whether the list has M before iteration, however unless this is needed for the iteration itself, it will unnecessarily increase your method complexity to O(2n) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Add `continue;` in If condition

```
if (list.get(i).equals("M")) {
                flag = "M";
                continue;
}
```

Comment: continue doesn't work its still looping through all the conditions

Comment: As per your question "but want to continue further operations in that for loop", you want to skip current iteration and continue with next one right? When compiler find continue statement it will skip current iteration that is it will not execute next statements of the loop and continue with next one.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() && !"M".equals(flag); i++) {
```

Note the use of `"M".equals(flag)` so we don't throw a `NPE` when `flag` is `null`.